# Включение в проект umbrella приложения Phoenix 1.5.1

Tags: elixir

При установке согласно https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/installation.html#content на этапе запуска сервера возникает ошибка:

```
== Compilation error in file lib/hello_web/endpoint.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) invalid :json_decoder option. The module Poison is not loaded and could not be found
    (plug) lib/plug/parsers/json.ex:44: Plug.Parsers.JSON.validate_decoder!/1
    (plug) lib/plug/parsers/json.ex:31: Plug.Parsers.JSON.init/1
    (plug) lib/plug/parsers.ex:249: anonymous fn/3 in Plug.Parsers.convert_parsers/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1948: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (plug) lib/plug/parsers.ex:230: Plug.Parsers.convert_parsers/2
    (plug) lib/plug/parsers.ex:226: Plug.Parsers.init/1
    (plug) lib/plug/builder.ex:304: Plug.Builder.init_module_plug/4
    (plug) lib/plug/builder.ex:288: anonymous fn/5 in Plug.Builder.compile/3
```

Poison использую в двух приложениях проекта.
Приложение устанавливалось в подкаталог /apps наравне с другими.

При этом установка приложения в корне  не вызывает таких ошибок. Но так оставлять не хотелось бы, потому что web сервер всего лишь вспомогательное, скромное по функционалу приложение в рамках проекта.

Как исправить (возможно в настройках проекта)?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что Вы запускаете приложение из подпапки? (`./apps/app_name/`)

Comment: Да. Так и есть.

Answer (score 0):

Если я все правильно понял, то ошибка заключается в том, что при запуске приложения амбреллы недоступна библиотека `Poison`.

---

Если запустить отдельное приложение амбреллы, оно не будет включать в себя другие приложения, расположенные по соседству. Также оно не будет включать в себя их зависимости.

Вы можете добавить в `mix.exs` файл приложения (`./apps/app_name/mix.exs`) зависимость [Poison](https://hex.pm/packages/poison).

---

Также рекомендую Вам ознакомиться с [документацией](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Release.html), в которой описано как можно сформировать различные релизы с указанием конкретных приложений и зависимостей.

Comment: Отчего же, я запускаю другие приложения из главного через супервизор и зависимостями активно пользуюсь.

Вот фрагмент deps секции основного приложения

   {:httpoison, "~> 1.6"},
   {:poison, "~> 4.0"},
   {:codepagex, "~> 0.1.4"}

Здесь же подключены и мои приложения.

Comment: Если запустить приложение "из главного", то тогда все зависимости будут скомпилированы, все верно. Вы же говорите, что запускаете приложение из его директории отдельно?

Comment: Ради теста просто решил запустить phoenix-приложение вручную интерактивно из iex. Все же мои остальные приложения допускают автономию запуска для локальной отладки.

Comment: В таком случае это поведение корректно, так как у подприложения нет скомпилированных зависимостей основного проекта :) Это можно исправить, добавив недостающие зависимости в его внутренний `mix.exs`, о чем уже написал ранее.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `{:poison, "~> 4.0"}` в `mix.exs` внутреннего приложения и запустить его.

Comment: Да. Ошибка исчезла. Просто до сих пор глобальные зависимости "поставлялись" приложениям проекта "на автомате". Например, httpoison и poison используются другими приложениями и в их локальных mix.exs я не прописывал зависимости.
Спасибо.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107951/discussion-between-george-turin-and-alexandr-sysoev).